# O que são Proxy, Gateway e Tunnel no protocolo HTTP?

Tags: http

Na especificação do protocolo HTTP, mais precisamente na [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), é previsto a possibilidade de existir entidades intermediárias entre o *user agent* (UA), entidade que efetua a requisição HTTP, e o *origin server* (O), entidade que responderá à requisição.

As setas para a direita indicam o trajeto da requisição HTTP e as setas para a esquerda indicam o trajeto da resposta HTTP. As entidades A, B e C são as entidades intermediárias que se comunicam entre si, com o *user agent* ou *origin server* através de quatro conexões HTTP.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As três entidades intermediárias descritas são:

1. *Proxy*
2. *Gateway*
3. *Tunnel*

Sendo que cada entidade intermediária pode operar como um *origin server*, *proxy*, *gateway* ou *tunnel*, dependendo da natureza da requisição HTTP que será por ela tratada.

O que eu gostaria de saber é qual a diferença entre os três tipos de entidades intermediárias e quando cada um é utilizado na prática. Também se é possível a existência de apenas uma entidade intermediária ou se são relacionadas a ponto de só existirem mutuamente.

Comment: Veja se ajuda a solução de uma pergunta parecida no Fórum em inglês: <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377679/whats-distinction-of-http-proxy-tunnel-gateway

Answer (score 12):

Segundo a [`RFC 7230`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) segue as definições:

Definição de Proxy:

> Um "proxy" é um agente de encaminhamento de mensagem que é selecionado pelo cliente, geralmente através de regras de configuração locais, para receber pedidos de algum tipo de URI absoluto e tentar satisfazer esses pedidos via tradução através da interface HTTP. Algumas traduções são mínimas, como, por exemplo, pedidos de proxy para URIs "http", enquanto outros pedidos podem exigir tradução para protocolos de nível de aplicativo completamente diferentes. Proxies costumam ser usados para agrupar as solicitações HTTP de uma organização através de um intermediário comum por causa da segurança, serviços de anotação ou armazenamento em cache compartilhado. Alguns proxies são projetados para aplicar transformações a mensagens selecionadas ou cargas úteis enquanto elas estão sendo encaminhadas.

Definição de Gateway:

> Um "gateway" (conhecido como "proxy reverso") é um intermediário que atua como um servidor de origem para a conexão de saída, mas traduz pedidos recebidos e encaminha-os para outro servidor ou servidores. Os gateways geralmente são usados para encapsular serviços de informação legados ou não confiáveis, para melhorar o desempenho do servidor através do armazenamento em cache do "acelerador" e para permitir o particionamento ou balanceamento de carga de serviços HTTP em várias máquinas.

Definição de Túnel:

> Um "túnel" funciona como um relé cego entre duas conexões sem alterar as mensagens. Uma vez ativo, um túnel não é considerado uma parte da comunicação HTTP, embora o túnel possa ter sido iniciado por uma solicitação HTTP. Um túnel deixa de existir quando ambas as extremidades da conexão retransmitida estão fechadas. Os túneis são usados para estender uma conexão virtual através de um intermediário, como quando a `Transport Layer Security` (TLS, [[RFC5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246)]) é usada para estabelecer uma comunicação confidencial através de um proxy de `firewall` compartilhado.

Comment: A RFC 7230 torna obsoleta a RFC 2616, então talvez seria interessante atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Atualizei. O que fiz foi traduzir as definições que estão no link.

Answer (score 6):

Vou tentar explicar a diferença com alguns exemplos. Lendo apenas a definição na [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) eu, particularmente, tenho problemas de entender o significado em termos mais práticos.

## Gateway

Imagine que ele é a porta de saída para uma outra rede. Fazendo uma [analogia](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/difference-between-a-proxy-server-a-gateway) simples, se seu computador é uma casa e a Internet fica do lado de fora, o Gateway é a porta. Sem a porta, você fica trancado na casa.

O Gateway simplesmente faz o roteamento das requisições que chega a ele para a rede interna. É por esta razão que quando você precisa acessar a Internet em casa, o Gateway é o roteador da sua residência; é ele que dará o acesso a outra rede (Internet) sem restrições.

## Proxy

Ele serve para proteger a rede externa. Usando a analogia da casa, é uma forma de deixar que você veja do lado de fora da casa, mas apenas o que ele quer que você veja.

Diferente do Gateway, o Proxy consegue fazer vários filtros e redirecionamentos, permitindo ou barrando os acessos conforme ele desejar, mantendo todos os computadores da rede anônimos. Normalmente é usado por empresas para restringir/controlar o acesso a Internet.

Um servidor Proxy que recebe as requisições e as repassa sem modificações também pode ser chamado de Gateway. [Comumente](https://web.archive.org/web/20130301235707/http://www.ukproxyserver.org/transparent-proxy/) este tipo de Proxy é chamado de Servidor Proxy Transparente.

## Tunnel

O Gateway e o Proxy agem como intermediários da conexão. Este não é o caso do *Tunnel*, pois os dados de um protocolo são encapsulados dentro de um outro protocolo, exigindo um software na origem e destino para enviar/receber as informações.

Usando a analogia da casa, seria como se você cavasse um túnel direto para a outra casa (rede) no qual deseja se comunicar, sem usar intermediários.

Se comparado ao Proxy, envolve menos [burocracia](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg-old/1999SepDec/0077.html), pois este pode exigir autenticação, pode adicionar um identificador dele no header, pode responder usando cache, etc. Já com *Tunnel* todas as requisições e respostas são passadas de forma intacta.

Na prática, as VPNs são um bom exemplo para entender o conceito de *Tunnel*.

Answer (score 5):

Proxy e servidor possuem definições que utilizam a palavra **programa**. No entanto, para o gateway isso não acontece. Essa deve ser uma das diferenças que você deve notar.

Tente comparar um proxy e um gateway por sua manipulação de solicitação. Um proxy:

> "Os pedidos são atendidos internamente ou passando eles para frente, com 
>   **possível translação**, a outros servidores."

Ele essencialmente *pode* alterar a solicitação ou responder com o que passa por ele.

A definição de geteway é:

> "Atua como intermediário para algum outro servidor. Ao contrário de um proxy, um
>   Gateway recebe pedidos como se fosse o servidor de origem para o
>   Recurso solicitado; O cliente requerente pode não estar ciente de que ele
>   está se comunicando com um gateway ".

Assim, o gateway neste contexto recebe e entrega o que quer que passa por ele.

Um Tunnel é como um tubo com um ponto em cada extremidade. O programa ou servidor intermediário não está ciente dessa conexão. Esse Tunnel pode ser iniciado por uma solicitação HTTP. O tunnel será finalizado quando qualquer extremidade decidir largar o tunnel.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377679/whats-distinction-of-http-proxy-tunnel-gateway

Comment: Um proxy servindo a resposta conforme a requisição também não estaria atuando como o servidor de origem para o cliente?

Comment: Um servidor proxy pode, opcionalmente, alterar a requisição do cliente ou a resposta do servidor e, algumas vezes, pode disponibilizar este recurso mesmo sem se conectar ao servidor especificado. Pode também atuar como um servidor que armazena dados em forma de cache em redes de computadores.

Comment: Um Proxy muitas vezes não realiza o contato com o servidor origem, ele pode servir o conteúdo em cache e inclusive modifica-lo.