# É possível editar um response http?

Tags: c#

É possível editar um response http antes dele ser renderizado pelo navegador?
Algo com esse esquema:
Recebimento do response -> Edição do response -> Streaming do response ao navegador.

Comment: de qual navegador está falando ?

Comment: Ai que está o problema, eu já consegui realizar esse procedimento em um webbrowser, mas eu quero expandir isso para qualquer navegador que a pessoa esteja utilizando, eu já vi algo parecido em alguns aplicativos, mas não consigo pensar em um jeito de fazer isso.

Comment: então.... se for o chrome... teria q ter uma extenção no chrome que faz isso... mesmo pro mozilla... iexplorer que teria a possibilidade de fazer pelo C#, mas o navegador deveria ser iniciado pela aplicação em C# e não pelo windows... acho bem complicado, talvez o mais simples seja o chrome. os adblock devem funcionar dessa forma

Comment: O antivírus da kaspersky faz algo semelhante sem extensões, ele adiciona uma tag <script></script> em todas as páginas que você acessa, independente do seu navegador. Não tem como fazer isso identificando o response http na placa de rede antes de ser enviada ao navegador?

Comment: não... na placa de rede ainda estaria em pacotes tcp, e certamente particionados, além de criptografados, ssl e tal, kaspersky deve ter um componente que é instalado junto para cada navegador, semelhante a programas de acesso a banco. Avast tem algo semelhante, mas para outros propósitos, e também é com componentes instalados no navegador

Comment: Tem como fazer isso com um proxy?

Comment: aí já não consigo te ajudar, nunca fiz algo do tipo =/

Comment: Só usar um servidor de Proxy.

Comment: Tem como detalhar melhor o que deseja fazer? Deseja fazer essa modificação no lado do cliente, logo após receber a resposta, ou ainda no lado do servidor, antes de encaminhar a resposta? Sem ser esses dois, você pode usar um proxy como entidade intermediária ([O que são Proxy, Gateway e Tunnel no protocolo HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227907/5878)), assim como o LINQ comentou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar alguns métodos da classe [`HttpResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) enquanto ainda estiver no servidor. Em geral frameworks como o ASP.NET puro e o ASP.NET MVC te dão uma variável de instância pertencente à página ou ao controlador para isso. I.e.: você pode fazer algo como:

```
Response.Write("Isto é um teste");
```

E esse texto será incluso na resposta enviada ao navegador.

Quando o controle sai do servidor a manipulação da resposta se torna mais complexa, por dois motivos:

- A edição de conteúdo transmitido pela rede tem que ser feita "na unha", já que fora os protocolos utilizados na rede (IP/TCP/HTTP/SOAP, por exemplo), o formato das mensagens não costuma ser padronizado. Você vai escovar strings e isso pode ser um trabalho muito ingrato.
- Qualquer ação nesse sentido é um ataque do tipo *man-in-the-middle*, então esteja pronto para lidar com mecanismos de segurança que vão te atrapalhar a depender do contexto.